# aws apigateway adding examples when generating swagger or openapi

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm actually doing some documentation for an api using aws api gateway schema and documentation so I can simply export openapi file from the service. I also wanted to ad some request body example form some complex model like here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/ in the "Request and Response Body Examples" part, but I couldn't find how to add it anywhere, did I miss something or it's supported by apigateway ?

Thank you for your time